# Are there vector fields which are gradients with respect to one metric but not another?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations, differential-topology

Is it possible for a vector field on a smooth manifold $M$ to be a gradient with respect to a Riemannian metric $g$, but not a gradient with respect to a different Riemannian metric $h$?

For completeness: the gradient of a smooth function $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ with respect to the metric $g$ is the unique smooth vector field $\text{grad}_g\,  f$ on $M$ such that for all smooth vector fields $Y$ on $M$, $$g(\text{grad}_g\,  f, Y) = df(Y).$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the  vector  field  $$X=(y-10x)\partial_x-x\partial_y$$ it is  not  a  gradient  vector  field  with respect to the  standard  Riemannian  metric  of  $\mathbb{R}^2$  but  it  is  a  gradient vector  field with respect to the Riemannian  metric  $$g=5dx\otimes dx-dx\otimes dy -dy\otimes dx +5dy\otimes dy$$

For  this  metric we have $X=grad_g f$  where $f(x,y)=-1/2(49x^2-10xy+y^2)$
The  motivation for  consideration of  a  big number as $10$ in $X$ is  the  following:

**Note:** If we choose  the vector field  $$X=(y-\epsilon x)\partial_x-x\partial_y$$ where  $|\epsilon|<2$ then there is  no  an  analytic  Riemannian  metric $g$ with  $X=\text{grad}_g$. Because the orbits tend to the  singularity at the origin, spirally. This means  that the  singularity is  a  focus singularity. On the  other  hand  the  Riemannian  version of the  [Thom  gradient  conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_conjecture) says  that if  an  orbit of  an analytic gradient vector  field tends to  an isolated singularity then it must approach to  the  singularity  in a  specific direction. Of  course a  focus singularity violate this condition.

**Shahshahani Gradient:**
As an interesting example,  please  search  "Shahshahani  Gradient". This  gradient  corresponds  to a  Riemannian  metric on the phase space of  certain  vector  field  which is  not a  gradient  system with respect to the  standard metric  but is  a  gradient  vector  field  with respect to the  Shahshahani  Riemannian  metric.

See here for some  explanation on [Shahshahani  metric.](https://books.google.com/books?id=AdKnOpCsH3gC&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=Shahshahani++Gradient++gradient+vector++field&source=bl&ots=huTRLFy49f&sig=LKs-EYCuLjnlK5t9KtOO18R2_fA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjZkOu_8bbbAhW0yqYKHUltC-g4ChDoAQgrMAI#v=onepage&q=Shahshahani%20%20Gradient%20%20gradient%20vector%20%20field&f=false)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the reference to the Shahshahani metric/gradient. I hadn't heard of that before.

Comment: @MatthewKvalheim  You are well come!

Answer (score 5):

First note that a vector field $v$ can be written as a gradient of a function wrt. to a metric $g$ iff the corresponding one-form $\flat_g v$ is exact, i.e. $\flat_g v=df$ for some smooth function $f$, where $\flat_g$ is the isomorphism $TM\to T^{\ast}M$ induced by the metric $g$. If $M$ is contractible, any differential form $\omega$ is exact iff it is closed, i.e. $d\omega=0$.

Thus, take any vector field $v$ on, say, $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $d(\flat_g v)=0$. It is easy to perturb $g$ into another metric $h$ such as to achieve $d(\flat_h v)\neq 0$.

Comment: That's a nice explanation! It seems obvious now when you put it that way. Thank you. I wish I could accept more than one answer.